# Unreachable Statement with Break

Tags: java, switch-statement, break

So I had a previous question but realized I posted the wrong offending code. I've marked the offending statements below.

What I am trying to do is set the precedence for each of the operators with that switch statement.

Maybe someone could point me in the right direction.

Just as a note, I AM running JAVA 7 so String Switch will work.

Code

opType.java

```
import java.io.*;

public final class opType {

   public static opType ADD = new opType( "Add" );
   public static opType SUB = new opType( "Sub" );
   public static opType MULT = new opType( "Mult" );
   public static opType DIV = new opType( "Div" );
   public static opType MOD = new opType( "Mod" );
   public static opType LPAR = new opType( "LParen" );
   public static opType RPAR = new opType( "RParen" );

   protected String name;

   private opType( String n )
   {
      name = n;
   }

   public String getName()
   {
      return name;
   }
```

Operator.java

```
public class Operator extends Token {

    protected opType val;

    public boolean isOperator() { return true; }
    public boolean isOperand() { return false; }

    protected int getPrec()
    {

        switch(val.getName())
        {
            case "LParen": 
            {
                return 0;
                break; //unreachable
            }

            case "RParen": 
            {
                return 0;
                break; //unreachable
            }

            case "Mult":
            {
                return 1;
                break; //unreachable
            }
            case "Div": 
            {   
                return 1;
                break; //unreachable
            }
            case "Mod": 
            {   
                return 1;
                break; //unreachable
            }
            case "Add": 
            {   
                return 2;
                break; //unreachable
            }
            case "Sub": 
            {   
                return 2;
                break; //unreachable
            }
        }

            return 0;
    }

    public static int compare( Operator a, Operator b )
    {
        if( a.getPrec() == b.getPrec() )
            return 0;
        else if( a.getPrec() < b.getPrec() )
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;
    }

    public opType getVal() { return val; }

    public Operator( opType v ) { val = v; }

}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you put a `return`, then the function returns before the `break` is executed and therefore the `break` will never be reached.

Instead you could use a variable that you set to a desired value and after the switch return that. Or just get rid of the `break` statements.

Answer (score 7):

you already have `return` which will make the `break` unreachable

Comment: Can you clarify which return you mean? Do you mean the ones before the break of the one outside the loop. Sorry, I am a noob when it comes to Java.

Comment: What he means is that in all of your cases, you have `return x; break;` where `x` is some constant. Since you have those returns, the breaks never get executed.

Answer (score 4):

The reason that the code is unreachable is due to the `return` behaving like a `break` in that context - they both complete abruptly.

If a statement completes abruptly, then execution at that line is immediately returned to its appropriate context; if it's a `break`, it'll attempt to either exit the `switch` or return to its associated label if one exists; if it's a `return`, it will return to its caller, with or without a value.

This is why the code is unreachable:  **the line of code after the `return` *can not* be reached.**

To really understand what that means or entails, we have to look at the Java Language Specification, specifically [14.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.1):

> Every statement has a normal mode of execution in which certain
>   computational steps are carried out. The following sections describe
>   the normal mode of execution for each kind of statement.
>
> If all the steps are carried out as described, with no indication of
>   abrupt completion, the statement is said to complete normally.
>   However, certain events may prevent a statement from completing
>   normally:
>
> The break (§14.15), continue (§14.16), and return (§14.17) statements
>   cause a transfer of control that may prevent normal completion of
>   statements that contain them.
>
> Evaluation of certain expressions may throw exceptions from the Java
>   Virtual Machine (§15.6). An explicit throw (§14.18) statement also
>   results in an exception. An exception causes a transfer of control
>   that may prevent normal completion of statements.
>
> If such an event occurs, then execution of one or more statements may
>   be terminated before all steps of their normal mode of execution have
>   completed; such statements are said to complete abruptly.
>
> An abrupt completion always has an associated reason, which is one of
>   the following:
>
> - A `break` with no label
> - A `break` with a given label
> - A `continue` with no label
> - A `continue` with a given label
> - A `return` with no value
> - A `return` with a given value
> - A `throw` with a given value, including exceptions thrown by the Java
>     Virtual Machine
>
> The terms "complete normally" and "complete abruptly" also apply to
>   the evaluation of expressions (§15.6). The only reason an expression
>   can complete abruptly is that an exception is thrown, because of
>   either a throw with a given value (§14.18) or a run-time exception or
>   error (§11, §15.6).
>
> If a statement evaluates an expression, abrupt completion of the
>   expression always causes the immediate abrupt completion of the
>   statement, with the same reason. All succeeding steps in the normal
>   mode of execution are not performed.
>
> Unless otherwise specified in this chapter, abrupt completion of a
>   substatement causes the immediate abrupt completion of the statement
>   itself, with the same reason, and all succeeding steps in the normal
>   mode of execution of the statement are not performed.
>
> Unless otherwise specified, a statement completes normally if all
>   expressions it evaluates and all substatements it executes complete
>   normally.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement effectively exits the method immediately. Since you've placed return statements inside the `switch` block for each `case`, whichever `case` is matched will, according to your code, return whatever value is indicated immediately. The `break` therefore cannot be executed, hence the error. You have two options:

1- Set a value, and return at the end of the method:

```
protected int getPrec(){
    int prec = 0;
    switch(val.getName()) {
        case "LParen": 
            prec = 0;
            break;
        case "RParen": 
            prec = 0;
            break;
        case "Mult":
            prec = 1;
            break;
        case "Div": 
            prec = 1;
            break;
        case "Mod": 
            prec = 1;
            break;
        case "Add": 
            prec = 2;
            break;
        case "Sub": 
            prec = 2;
            break;
        default:
            prec = 0;
            break; // technically unnecessary since we're at the end already but adding for completeness.
    }
        return prec;
}
```

2- Ditch the `break;` statements and keep the `return` statements as you've written them.

Personally I would prefer the first option as its cleaner and more readable to me. Plus it makes it easier to expand whatever actions need to be done in one or more cases if need be in the future.

By the way, watch your naming convention. You presently have:

```
public final class opType // bad naming
```

Since this is a class, the Java standard is to capitalize the first letter of the class. So it should be:

```
public final class OpType // good naming
```

Comment: The naming convention is not mine, these are classes given by my instructor that we MUST use. But thank you for the heads up, I will keep it in mind.

Comment: @SlashTag Hmm I see, that's odd. I would mention this to your instructor then, if that is the case, because they really should not be teaching bad programming habits / practices in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can comment the line `return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)`
after commenting this line the code will run.
**This Works for me**

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      //return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);  
       switch (item.getItemId()) {
           case R.id.aboutUS:
          Intent i = new   Intent("com.code.myapp.ABOUT");
                 startActivity(i);
             break;
 
           case R.id.preferences:
 
             break;
       }
       return false;
      }
```